# Is css @import google font better than a local copy for site optimization

Tags: css, optimization, font-face, webfonts

In terms of site optimization and speed; is it better to include a font locally or use a css @import? (I'm using google's web-fonts)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a test on your own.  The simplest way to do so is to use a developer tools console in your browser and to check a network section to see how how long it takes for the files to be loaded.  It is possible that your web server may dish out files slower or faster than google.

Additionally, some browsers, like Firefox, by default, may not include font files downloaded from a different domain.  To make sure your site renders as expected, I would serve font files from within the domain that the user visits.